# Access - Plotting two time series on one graph

Tags: ms-access, plot, graph

I am quite new to access and really struggling to plot my Running total data as two lines (one for 2019, one for 2020) against week number.  Currently just get one line.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this in MS Access.  Access is really, really bad for plotting and charting.  You can check the link below.  Maybe you will get some ideas from that.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-chart-on-a-form-or-report-1a463106-65d0-4dbb-9d66-4ecb737ea7f7

Or, consider exporting your results from Access to Excel.  You can pass data between Access and Excel using VBA and just a few lines of code.  You can definitely plot multiple time series arrays in Excel.

https://peltiertech.com/multiple-time-series-excel-chart/

https://peltiertech.com/plot-two-time-series-with-different-dates/